# reputation on joining new site

Tags: support, reputation

I have joined Programmers recently but I have not received the 100 reputation as stated in FAQ about increasing reputation. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Association bonus is given to users who earned at least $200$ on at least one site.

When you reach this level, you will get  extra $100$ points on every site where you have an account.

Comment: So, if I have 200 points and then join another site, will I get the the points on the new site?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty Yes. And also if you join  first and get $200$ later. The order does not matter.